# When and where does Play set the Content-Length header?

Tags: scala, http, playframework, content-length

I'm trying to log every request my play app is receiving using the [Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format).

I can get all of these fields in a [Filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Filter) just fine except for body length.

I noticed that making a call to Play return the `Content-Length` since Play automatically figures it out without you tell it (unless you are doing funky things  with [Chunked Responses](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/JavaStream) and such).

This would lead me to believe that, in a Filter, I can simply call

```
next(rh).map{ response => log(response.header.headers.get("Content-Length")); response }
```

But this returns `None`! Yet I see the header when I curl any call. This means that the `Content-Length` must be set after the `Filter`, but where? And how/can I access it from `Global.scala`? If not, then anyone knows of a simple way get this info (programmatically or otherwise).

I'm using Play 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply content length is set in the iteratee that writes data back to the netty response, where it chooses if it should set content length or start chunking the response based on what is pushed to the iteratee, so it is actually not calculated anywhere that you can access in your filter. You can check the source where this is happening here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/netty/NettyResultStreamer.scala#L119